# C#: Использование асинхронных методов

Tags: c#, async-await, асинхронность, task

Обычно я использую следующий асинхронный код:

```
private async Task<string> Method()
    {
        var promise = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            string answer = null;
            //тут что то происходит
            promise.SetResult(answer);
        });

        var result = await promise.Task;
        return result;
    }
```

И вызываю его так: `await Method();`

Если мне нужно записать ответ метода в переменную, я делаю это так:

`string x = await Method();`

Но недавно я нашёл вот этот код:

```
public static Task TryInvokeMethodAsync(Action func)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Task>();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                func.Invoke();
                tcs.SetResult(null);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                tcs.SetCanceled();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                tcs.SetException(ex);
            }
        });

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Который вызывается так:

```
TryInvokeMethodAsync(() => AnyMethod());
```

То есть с помощью этого метода можно любой метод вызвать асинхронно. Но как получить от него ответ (например, тот же string)? TryInvokeMethodAsync возвращает Task, если пытаться получить от него ответ так:

```
var x = TryInvokeMethodAsync(() => AnyMethod());
```

А через await он вообще не вызывается, даже если сделать его async.

И вообще, правильный ли асинхронный код я использую?

P.S. как правильно использовать try-catch в первом методе, который указан в самом начале?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему бы не так

```
private async Task<string> Method()
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        string answer = null;
            //тут что то происходит
        return answer;
    }); 
}
```

или так

```
public static async Task TryInvokeMethodAsync(Action func)
{   
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {   
        func.Invoke();      
    }); 
}
```

Или даже так

```
public static async Task<T> TryInvokeMethodAsync<T>(Func<T> func)
{   
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return func.Invoke();
    });
}
```

А может и так (хотя тут уже непонятно зачем :))

```
public static async Task<T> TryInvokeMethodAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
{
    return await func();
}
```

Comment: Почему бы не убрать `async` и `await`?

Comment: @PetSerAl можно и убрать, если стек особо не интересен

Comment: @PetSerAl сегодня только где то обсуждали [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)

Comment: Я нашёл только одно предложение в данной статье, которое применимо к примеру, на который я оставлял комментарий: *Do consider eliding when the method is just a passthrough or overload.*

Comment: @PetSerAl замечательно, я вроде и не спорил с вами, просто поделился ссылкой на статью на релевантную тему.